# dividing the last value of list to the previous value

Tags: python, list, math

i'm programming a simple project for Guessing the next number in python ,in this part , i need to divide the last number of "raw","lst","age" list to the  previous number only in each list ...

here is my example code

```
raw = [1,5,10]
lst = [2, 6 , 12]
age = [8 , 16 , 48]
```

therefore , i want to divide only **The last two values**
and the output like that :

```
[2]
[2]
[3]
```

do you know any code , method or function for that? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply access the **values** over **their indices**:

```
result = l[-1] / l[-2] # replace 'l' with your list-variable(s)
```